# Connecting to Mantis Bug Tracker via .Net

Tags: bug-tracking, mantis, compact-framework2.0, bug-tracker, bugtracker.net

I tried to connect and add an issue to Mantis Bug Tracker serwis, but no success. I am using .Net Framework 2.0(Compact FrameWork). My Bug Tracker Service have a few projects and i want to add issue to specific one including user, time and description. I tried this, but nothing happened

```
        Mantis.IssueData issue = new Mantis.IssueData();
        issue.id = "1";
        issue.description ="Test issue";
        issue.date_submitted = DateTime.Now;
        issue.description = "Test description";
        MantisConnect mantisConnect = new Mantis.MantisConnect();
        mantisConnect.Beginmc_issue_add(Properties.Resources.MantisLogin, Properties.Resources.MantisPassword, issue,null,null);
```

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: I have no idea about .NET, but can you capture the network traffic and post it here? Make sure to remove username/password/hostname data